# Access key-value pairs stored in appsettings.json file in IOption class

Tags: c#, json, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm storing an array of key-value pairs in my `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "ApplicationSettings": {
    ...
    "CellularProviders": [
      {
        "Cingular": "cingularme.com"
      },
      {
        "Nextel": "vtext.com"
      },
      {
        "Sprint": "messaging.sprintpcs.com"
      },
      {
        "T-Mobile": "tmomail.net"
      },
      {
        "Verizon": "messaging.nextel.com"
      },
      {
        "Virgin Mobile": "vmobl.com"
      }
    ]
    ...
}
```

Currently, I use a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` in the POCO class that is populated in `Startup.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationSettings
{
    ...
    public List<Dictionary<string,string>> CellularProviders { get; set; }

}
```

Is this the recommended way of representing an array of key-value pairs?

Moreover, I'd like to be able to manage this setting in Azure, using the app's Settings section:

[image]

What's the correct way to represent an array of key-value pairs in this context?

Answer (score 1):

You can't place `JSON` into App Settings as it is a simple set of key-value pairs. In order to override the settings within your `appsettings.json` you need to represent the full path, segmented by `:`s, as the key (the value remains the same):

For example, one `key` would be `CellularProviders:Cingular` with the `value` set to `cingularme.com`.

```
CellularProviders:Cingular = cingularme.com
CellularProviders:Nextel = vtext.com
CellularProviders:Sprint = messaging.sprintpcs.com
CellularProviders:T-Mobile = tmomail.net
CellularProviders:Verizon = messaging.nextel.com
CellularProviders:VirginMobile = vmobl.com
```

As for converting this to a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, I'm not sure I understand why you're using a "List of Dictionaries" instead of `Dictionary<string, string>`.

A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is pretty much a `List<T>` of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` objects (note, this is a bit of an overgeneralization). You should consider using this instead:

```cs
public Dictionary<string,string> CellularProviders { get; set; }
```

This will allow you to easily lookup values in the collection like this:

```cs
var providerValue = CellularProviders["Cingular"];
```